# Why do I get \ in output when using deparse in R?

Tags: r

Why and how do I get rid of the \ in deparse:

```
variable <- "Only output text"
deparse(variable)
```

Output:
`[1] "\"Only output text\""`

I would just like to get "Only text" as output.

For example this does not work:

```
 result_description <- paste("result =", cat(deparse(variable)))
result_description
```

Comment: "\" escapes the quote. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: If you do `cat(deparse(example))` you will see that the `\\` is not "really" there

Comment: @MitchellGraham thanks the info; please see added information. thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks but it does not really work in the context I want to use it, apologise for previously  unclear question.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `cat(paste("result =", deparse(variable)))`. Though still unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Aurèle I want to save the result in the variable (within a function) so that the variable is part of a list of output from a function. I hope that makes more sense... That is, I want to be able to save it for later.

Comment: @Gorp I didn't intend for it to "work" to solve a problem. I'm just point out that the problem isn't the one you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is simply telling you that the double quote following it is part of the string itself. So it is not a `\` that is the undesired character in your text, it is the double quotes. You can remove these with a `gsub` command very easily:

```r
variable <- "Only output text"
gsub("\"", "", deparse(variable))
#> [1] "Only output text"
```

However, it's really not clear why you would do this. The line `gsub("\"", "", deparse(variable))` is identical to `variable`:

```
gsub("\"", "", deparse(variable)) == variable
#> [1] TRUE
```